# How to make a column update automatically in another table when a record is inserted into the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

When a record is inserted into a table, `QuantityInHand` in the `Items` table should be updated automatically. The two tables are `Transactions.OrderDetails` and `Items.ItemDetails`.

I've tried something like this:

```
Create Trigger items.trgItemDetails
on items.ItemDetails
After update
As
   Begin
    Update items.ItemDetails
Set Items.itemDetails.QuantityInHand = ItemID
From Inserted
where inserted.ItemID = Items.ItemDetails
  End
```

Please, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand how triggers work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this using Triggers. 
check the link below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql